# How to detect that UIImagePickerController or UIDocumentPickerController window is opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am displaying overlay custom view in my app.
I find the key window, and I add my overlay custom view to the key window's subview.
And I set the overlay custom view's layer.zposition to 1.

When I open the `UIImagePickerController` or `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, I can't touch anything (It works nothing including cancel button in `UIImagePickerController`) and my overlay custom view is still exists.

So I'm trying to detect that `UIImagePickerController` or `UIDocumentPickerViewController` window is open. And If it's opened, I will make my overlay custom view's layer.zposition lower. And the Album will touched.

How can I get the event that `UIImagePickerController` or `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to know when these controllers are being presented:

1. You can override `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method for your root view controller, in that this method check if `viewControllerToPresent` is class type of `UIImagePickerController` or `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. and making the needed changes around overlay view.
2. I hope you only presenting these controllers from your source code, in that case before presenting these view controller you can make need change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked properly